# Приходит 2 сообщения вместо одного с почты wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Не пойму в чем проблема. Почему приходят по 2 сообщения. Указал в настройках только одного отправителя.

Нужно искать в php коде. Подскажите в какую сторону мне смотреть, где искать этот баг?

Comment: В настройках чего? Системы или плагина какого-то, 2 сообщения каких о чём. Как отправляются письма(плагин или функцией через файл functions.php)

Comment: @Walfter  В настройках плагина cforms. 2 сообщения администратору о новом заказе. Отправляются через плагин.

Comment: Возможно в нём проблема, посмотрите в настройках

Comment: Просто в CF7 есть пункт 2 сообщение, возможно и там тоже

Comment: @Walfter В настройках пересмотрел все. Ничего подозрительного. 2 сообщение (копия) - пустое. Такое ощущение, что скрипт запускается 2 раза, так как и письмо клиенту тоже приходит 2 раза

Comment: А где вызывается событие? Может быть такое что два раза заказ происходит?

Comment: @Walfter если бы я хоть знал в какую сторону смотреть...